# Is there a way to configure mouse controls on Minecraft pc?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an Apple mouse that has one button but it senses whether your finger is on the left or right side when you click. The scroll wheel also is "touchscreen". When I'm playing Minecraft, it will randomly scroll through my hot bar because of this. Is there a way to fix this or should i just buy a new mouse?

Comment: Minecraft will be responding to the input, based on the interpretation of the OS & Drivers. It's possible you could change the sensitivity of the scroll wheel function with in the OS somewhere.

Comment: Buy a new mouse. You may fix it for Minecraft, but it will keep giving you problems everywhere else.

Comment: I'd recommend buying a new mouse. Even though I'm sure you're attached to your magic mouse for general computer use, your gaming experience will be far better since games are designed for classic PC mice. You could probably find a client-side JAR mod to "fix" your mouse; try searching for "mouse tweak minecraft mod". With a JAR mod, you'll still be able to play on normal multiplayer servers and enter your existing worlds.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use the same mouse. If you are careful, it will not randomly scroll through. The scroll wheel is one way people select items, and because the mouse broadcasts smooth motion rather than clicks for scrolling, your game will interpret it as a huge amount of scroll clicks, and will appear to be randomly shifting through items. If you keep your pointer finger on the mouse, it shouldn't scroll like that. I was able to play the game fine with the mouse. If it really bothers you, I would recommend getting a mouse with actual individual buttons and a click scroll wheel.